# Unable to access working web app on docker windows container via localhost

Tags: asp.net, docker, localhost, containers, windows-container

I am using Windows 10 ver. 1709 and docker 17.09.1-ce-win42 (using windows containers). I successfully created an image of my ASP.NET app with microsoft/aspnet as base image.

In order to create the container, I use the command:

`docker run -d -p 8001:80 --name mycontainer myimage:v1`.

The container is created properly, and if I want to access the website, I use the container's IP address known thanks to

`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}' mycontainer`

Despite that, I want to access my app through localhost:8001 - it does not work.

Can someone tell me if and what I did something wrong? I have read that mapping in windows containers is problematic.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known bug in Winnat implementation of Windows. No solution to this but either access by internal IP address or access it externally.

[Details](https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/)

Will be fixed in next edition of Windows

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2017/11/06/available-to-windows-10-insiders-today-access-to-published-container-ports-via-localhost127-0-0-1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) Could you precise if I am wrong - right now Windows Insiders is a program for testing new features, it is nor released as a part of updating Windows right? Therefore I cannot access its functionality?

Comment: Correct, you have to sign up to this program and participate to get this functionality